# mvc empty webapi dependency injection

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Folks,
I am brand new to asp.net web APIs and need your help, I am using mvc4 Empty webapi project, I have a single controller called recordsController.
I have data that I need to persist in memory, and would like to use dependency injection to access this data model in my controller when a request arrives.

Is there any built in dependency injection that I can use ? if not, what is the best quick and dirty to accomplish this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

DO you want DI or data persistence, they are not the same thing at all.

If you want to use shared memory between all requests without using some kind of backend (Database,file and so on) then check MemoryCache -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx

DI is used for runtime type resolution and has nothing to do with data persistence.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Comment: Thank you ! what if I want DI ? is there a built in mechanism for this ?

Comment: This should get you started (updated with better example) 
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection